# DynamicRibbonBar apparait seulement quand j'ouvre une nouvelle onglet (Tab)

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik

La RibbonBar ouvre dans un onglet seuelement si j'ouvre une nouvelle onglet!

dans le MainWindow   #region Ribbonbar il ya la méthode  TabControl_SelectionChange  qsq se passe derriere lorque quelqu'un ouvre une nouvelle tab . le  ligne DynamicRibbonBarManager.ClearTabs();  s'exucte fréquemment .. voila

je ponse que le probleme est a cause de ca DynamicRibbonBarManager.ClearTabs()
mais comment resolu ca svp !!

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DynamicRibbonBarManager.ClearTabs();
            foreach (var itemAdd in e.AddedItems)
            {
                if (itemAdd != null
                    && itemAdd is TabItem
                    && (itemAdd as TabItem).Content is UserControl
                    && ((itemAdd as TabItem).Content as UserControl).DataContext is IWorkSpaceRibbonBar)
                {
                    DynamicRibbonBarManager.UpdateRabbonView((IWorkSpaceRibbonBar)((itemAdd as TabItem).Content as UserControl).DataContext);
                }
            }

        }
```

**DynamicRibbonBarManager.cs**

```
 public static void ClearTabs()
        {
            if (DictButtonActions != null)
            {
                foreach (var keyvaleur in DictButtonActions)
                {
                    if (keyvaleur.Key is RadRibbonButton)
                    {
                        (keyvaleur.Key as RadRibbonButton).Click -= RadRibbonButton_Click;
                    }
                    if (keyvaleur.Key is RadMenuItem)
                    {
                        (keyvaleur.Key as RadMenuItem).Click -= RadRibbonButton_Click;
                    }
                }
                DictButtonActions.Clear();
            }

            foreach (var tab in RibbonTabs)
            {
                RibbonBar.Items.Remove(tab);
            }
            RibbonTabs.Clear();
            if (RibbonBar != null && RibbonBar.Items != null)
            {
                (RibbonBar.Items[0] as RadRibbonTab).IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
```

**DynamicRibbonBarManager.cs**

```
 private static List<RadRibbonTab> GetRadRibbonTabs(string contextualGroupName, IEnumerable<AbstractItemRibbonBar> abstractItemRibbonBars)
        {
            var dicRadRibbonTabs = new Dictionary<string, RadRibbonTab>();
            foreach (var item in abstractItemRibbonBars)
            {
                if (item != null && !dicRadRibbonTabs.Keys.Contains(item.TabName))
                {
                    RadRibbonTab radRibbonTab = new RadRibbonTab();
                    radRibbonTab.Header = item.TabName;
                    radRibbonTab.ContextualGroupName = contextualGroupName;
                    foreach (var group in GetRibbonGroup(item.TabName, abstractItemRibbonBars))
                    {
                        radRibbonTab.Items.Add(group);
                    }

                    dicRadRibbonTabs.Add(item.TabName, radRibbonTab);
                }

            }

            List<RadRibbonTab> RadRibbonTabs = dicRadRibbonTabs.Values.ToList();

            if (RadRibbonTabs.Any())
            {
                RadRibbonTabs.First().IsSelected = true;
            }

            RibbonTabs.AddRange(RadRibbonTabs);
            return dicRadRibbonTabs.Values.ToList();

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please ask your question in English, this is the default language for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because : wrong language